# Creating a lib file from a visual studio project that is configured to generate a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have project that outputs a dll. Currently I have specified only a few functions to be exported. After compilation a dll file is generated and also a .lib file with the few exports that I had. I want to know if there is an easy way so that I can export all the classes to lib file. I cannot possibly add all statements for each class to .def file also I dont want to edit the code to change declaration of each method. Is there a visual studio setting that can tell the compiler to export all code.

Comment: You can use the .def file to create a .lib entirely without compiling code using LIB.EXE, but my guess is that is not exactly what you want. Either way you probably want to limit the number of entry points to your DLL, while keeping that narrow interface stable. COM has a pretty good approach to achieve this. If you want to avoid all the COM registration, interfaces may still be the best way here. Client-code knows all about the interface, DLL returns an instance implementing the interface. Of course, since interfaces are contracts, you would have to think it through up front.

Answer (score 1):

Use __declspec(dllexport) on the class declaration instead of using a .def file.  Exporting *everything* doesn't make a lot of sense and is not supported.  You pick what should be visible.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I thought about this and I agree that exporting everything might not make sense. The reason I want to do this is that I want test project to be able to link to any symbol of the production code (to be able to test it). Now, I dont want to edit the existing production code (class declarations) to be able to test it. I guess I am looking for a silver to bullet to do this but looks like its not possible.